# a question which is somhow related to law of large number

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, random-matrices

suppose that $\mathbf p = [p_1, p_2, ..., p_n]'$ is a random vector. (' == transpose) and each element of $\mathbf p$ like $p_i$ is a Gaussian random variable with zero mean ($\mathbb E(p_i)=0$) and variance $v_i$,($\mathbb E(p_i^2)=v_i$).

the elements of $\mathbf p$ are independent.

then what is the value of  $\frac{(\mathbf p'\times \mathbf p)}{n}$    when $n$ goes to infinity?

I know that when elements of p are having the same variance, the answer is equal to the variance, but what is the answer when the variance of each element is different?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$\frac{\boldsymbol p^{\top}\boldsymbol p}{n}=\frac{p_1^2+\cdots+p_n^2}{n}.$$
Given your comment about the variance,
it seems to me that what you're really interested in is
\begin{align}\tag{1}
\text{E}\left[\frac{\boldsymbol p^{\top}\boldsymbol p}{n}\right]=\frac{v_i+\cdots+v_n}{n}.
\end{align}
Indeed,
if $v_1=v_2=\cdots=v_n=v$,
then it is true that
$$\text{E}\left[\frac{\boldsymbol p^{\top}\boldsymbol p}{n}\right]=\frac{nv}{n}=v.$$

---

If the $v_i$ are not all equal to each other,
there is unfortunately no single solution to $(1)$.
However,
there exists criterions that can help you find upper/lower bounds for the limit, and sometimes even find what the limit is.

A limit of the form
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}n$$
where $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb R$ is known as a [Cesàro average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean) (or Cesàro mean).
One can show that if $a_n\to a$,
then $\sum_ia_i/n\to a$ as well.
I also recall seeing somewhere that,
in general,
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}n\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}n\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n,$$
which may at least give bounds for $(1)$ (I think this one is called the Stolz-Cesàro theorem).